# MYSQL database performance - size

Tags: php, mysql

I have several huge MYSQL tables (10gb+).  Will the performance of PHP queries I am running on one of these tables be influenced by the presence of other huge tables in the same database?  I am not running any queries on these other tables; they are neither directly nor indirectly linked to or referenced by my PHP query?

Comment: if you have enough memory for it all then there should'nt be any issue with not hitting those other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It deppends. You have to take in account the limited resources: memory and disc. 
Are any other program or proccess accessing those tables?
Also you have to considered how your tables are fiscal stored on the database. Are they on the same Filegroup? Another problem is fragmentation: You can think that diferent tables are fisicaly split but it depends on how your database grow. You can have scenarios where two different tables that grow toghether on time, have their data mixed fisically on the disk and have impact on the performance. Hope my answer helps you.